# How to drop a column in sql withina proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset with numerous columns that are completely null, I am attempting to create a proc which will delte a column if it is checked to have all nulls, but I am getting numerous errors, the most recent one is that it runs without errors but does not delete the column when no non null cells are found.

Any pointers would be massively appreciated, thank you.

```
create or alter proc delete_nulls
    (@columnname varchar(max))
as
begin;
        set @columnname = trim(@columnname) 
        if  (select count(@columnname) from dbo.dataset1 where @columnname is not null) < 0 
        alter table dbo.dataset1 
        drop column [@columnname]   
end;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is very product specific.)

Comment: @jarih  I use MS SQL server so Relational database management system

Comment: You can't use a variable to replace something that needs to be a literal. This, honestly, feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: This is a design question rather than programming one. Since enterprise server relational databases like SQL Server are part of core infrastructure they should be planned systems where databases, schemas, and tables are designed in advance of data and not rely on data to decide their structure. So having a stored procedure running DDL calls like `ALTER` may not be advisable and can cause maintenance challenges. In fact, having numerous (hundreds?) `varchar(max)` columns is questionable table design. Databases should not be dump sites of data.

Comment: In MS SQL Server, you have no way to pass a column name to a proc using a parameter like you're trying. The only way to achieve this is by putting together the SQL as a string and then execute that using `exec(@MySqlString)`.

Comment: You mean `sp_executesql` @Christian .

Comment: @Larnu Yes, you can use that too. But `exec()` works also.

Comment: Until you need to parametrise, which is why you should always use `sp_executesql`, @Christian . Also, there's no m in my alias.

Comment: THINK about your query! How can count() return a value that is less than zero? And generally speaking, you don't need to count to determine if something is present (or not). [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does this more efficiently. E.g., if exists (select * from ... where ...)

Comment: And THINK about your datatypes. There is simply no reason and no excuse to define a parameter as varchar(max) that will hold a single object name. Nor should your procedure have logic to accommodate programmer laziness. If the columnname (exactly as provided) does not exist you should probably throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

First, column names are of type sysname.  Second, you will need to use dynamic SQL.  Something along these lines. This still won't work as written because you will need to make the "IF" statement dynamic as well.  That logic you may want to pull outside the stored procedure.  And I agree with the comments above that this is just a start.  You want more logic to make sure the table and column actually exist.

```
create or alter proc delete_nulls
    (@columnname sysname, @tablename sysname)
as
begin;
        DECLARE @my_string NVARCHAR(1000)
        set @columnname = trim(@columnname) 
        if  (select count(@columnname) from dbo.dataset1 where @columnname is not null) < 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @my_string = N'
            alter table ' + @tablename + '
            drop column '+ @columnname 
            EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @my_string
        END
end;
```